# How to declare a global variable in Verilog?

Tags: variables, verilog, global

I am writing to ask how to declare a global variable in Verilog. What declared by `parameter` and `define` keywords are essentially constants, not variables.

What I need is the following:

```
`define Glitch 
module Cell ( Shift_In, Shift_Out_Screwed, Clk ); 
    input  Clk, Shift_In; 
    output  Shift_Out_Screwed; 
    wire  Shift_Out_Screwed; 
    wire  Shift_Out; 

    Inverter INV1 ( Shift_In, Shift_Out, Clk ); 
    assign Shift_Out_Screwed = Glitch ? ~Shift_Out : Shift_Out 
endmodule
```

This is a very simple glitch insertion. When `Glitch==1`, the original output is reversed; when `Glitch==0`, the original output is kept unchanged. I want the signal `Glitch` to be defined in an **external** simulation testbench.v file although it is declared and used here, and I **don't** want to add the signal `Glitch` to the input port list of the module `cell`. This is because that my real circuit is a very complicated one, and if I add an input port to a certain cell, there will be many other cells affected.

Does anyone know how to declare a global variable in Verilog?

Comment: Please state if you want is synthesizable or not.

Comment: No, it does NOT have to be synthesizable...

Comment: You might want to pass values for `Glitch` through [$value$plusargs](http://www.project-veripage.com/plusarg.php). Most simulators support this built-in function. [Here's an example](http://www.edaplayground.com/x/Rrp)

Comment: Thanks a lot e19293001! I will try it. And just my curiosity: what if I need it to be synthesizable?...

Comment: If `Glitch` is required to be overridden by testbench, then `parameter` is a suitable choice for synthesizablility. Else, passing a command line variable is also an alternative. Simply declaring `reg Glitch='b0` in global space can also be done.

Comment: Thanks sharvil111! The thing is: "Glitch" is **NOT** a constant, but a variable, or a signal. Can I simply write "reg glitch=0; #10; reg glitch=1;" outside the module "cell"?

Comment: `reg Glitch='b0` in global space. Then drive Glitch from **any** `initial` block in top module or any other module.

Comment: The better way to do this in simulation is to use `force` to set the value of `Glitch`, using its hierarchical path (`top.CellInstanceName.Glitch` or whatever). If you need this to be a variable in synthesis, youre going to have to have it be an input of the module.

Answer (score 1):

The problem you are wrestling with sounds like error injection.  You want the ability to inject a bit error on an output port from within a testbench.  You can do it like this:

```
module Cell ( Shift_In, Shift_Out_Screwed, Clk ); 
    input  Clk, Shift_In; 
    output  Shift_Out_Screwed; 
    wire  Shift_Out_Screwed; 
    wire  Shift_Out; 

    Inverter INV1 ( Shift_In, Shift_Out, Clk ); 

    `ifdef SIMULATION
    // This logic is used in simulation, but not synthesis.  Use care.
    logic Glitch = 1'b0;
    assign Shift_Out_Screwed = Glitch ? ~Shift_Out : Shift_Out 
    `else
    // This logic is used in synthesis, but not simulation.  Use care.
    assign Shift_out_Screwed = Shift_out;
    `endif
endmodule
```

Note that I use the "SIMULATION" preprocessor switch to hide the "Glitch" error injection from synthesis.  Use this technique with care to avoid creating simulation/synthesis mismatches.

In your testbench, you can induce a glitch in a specific instance of your cell by referencing the "Glitch" signal in the design hierarchy, like this:

```
initial begin
   ...
   @(posedge Clk); #1;
   $top.u_foo.u_bar.u_cell.Glitch = 1'b1;
   @(posedge Clk); #1;
   $top.u_foo.u_bar.u_cell.Glitch = 1'b1;
   ...
end
```

The above code snippet will inject one cycle of "Glitch".

As an alternative: a more traditional way of injecting errors is to use the "force" statement in the testbench to override a driven in a device under test.